# Nodes shut down during 'new' state

Tags: maas

I have installed MAAS (`apt -y install maas`) on Ubuntu Server amd64 16.04.2. My nodes are detected by the never leave the 'new' state. The reason is that the nodes shut down after the SSH key generation phase.

Here is a [typical messages log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/24279462/) from one of the nodes.

One thing that caused suspicion of something being wrong is this:

```
ci-info: no authorized ssh keys fingerprints found for user ubuntu
```

Yet I checked the [logs of another node with the same problem](http://paste.ubuntu.com/24279481/), but could not find that error message.

Am I missing something here?